# Dynamic programming based range minimum query

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x

I am implementing a DP-based range minimum query data structure and algorithm in Python 2.7. Any advice on algorithm time complexity improvements, code bugs or code style issues are appreciated.

[More information about range minimum query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query).

```
from collections import defaultdict
import random
def build_rmq(numbers):
    rmq_map = defaultdict(int) # key: tuple of (start, end) index, value: min value
    j = 0
    while 2 ** j - 1 < len(numbers):
        j += 1
    j -= 1
    # print j
    for step in range(0,j+1):
        for i in range(0, len(numbers)):
            if step == 0:
                rmq_map[(i,step)] = numbers[i]
                continue
            if i + 2 ** (step-1) < len(numbers):
                rmq_map[(i,step)] = min(rmq_map[(i, step-1)], rmq_map[(i + 2 ** (step-1), step-1)])
            else:
                rmq_map[(i,step)] = rmq_map[(i, step-1)]

    return rmq_map

def rmq_query(start, end, rmq_map):
    j = 0
    while start + 2 ** j - 1 <= end:
        j += 1
    j -= 1
    x = rmq_map[(start, j)]
    y = rmq_map[(end + 1 - 2 ** j, j)]
    return min(x,y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = [0,5,2,5,4,3,1,6,3]
    rmq_map = build_rmq(numbers)
    #print rmq_map
    start = random.randint(0, len(numbers)-1)
    end = random.randint(0, len(numbers)-1)
    if start > end:
        start, end = end, start
    print start, end, numbers[start:end+1]
    print rmq_query(start, end, rmq_map)
```

Answer (score 8):

#### 1. Review

1. There are no docstrings. What do these functions do? What do they return? How do I use them?
2. The function `build_rmq` constructs a persistent data structure which can then be queried by calling the function `rmq_query`. When you have a persistent data structure and functions that operate on it, this is good candidate for making into a class.
3. The comment on this line is not quite right:

   ```
   rmq_map = defaultdict(int) # key: tuple of (start, end) index, value: min value
   ```

   the second element of the key is a step, not an end index.
4. There is no need to use a `defaultdict` here, since the code always fills in the entry before looking it up. An ordinary dictionary would do fine.
5. This code:

   ```
   j = 0
   while 2 ** j - 1 < len(numbers):
       j += 1
   ```

   computes the smallest power of 2 that is greater than `len(numbers)`. It would be simpler to use [`int.bit_length`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length):

   ```
   j = len(numbers).bit_length()
   ```

   (In [ChatterOne's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/154057/11728) it is suggested that you use `int(log(len(numbers), 2))`. I think this is a dangerous suggestion, because `log` makes approximations that can lead to errors. For example,

   ```
   int(log(2**48 - 1, 2))
   ```

   evaluates to 48, but the correct result is 47. In order to check that these errors can't actually cause your code to fail, you need to do numerical analysis. This seems complicated and error-prone to me, compared to sticking with integer arithmetic where you know the results are exact.)
6. Similarly, this loop:

   ```
   j = 0
   while start + 2 ** j - 1 <= end:
       j += 1
   ```

   becomes:

   ```
   j = (end - start + 1).bit_length()
   ```
7. This code subtracts 1 from `j` and then adds it back again, which is not necessary:

   ```
   j -= 1
   for step in range(0,j+1):
   ```
8. `range(0, x)` can be abbreviated to `range(x)`.
9. `rmq_map[(i,step)]` does not need the parentheses: `rmq_map[i, step]` is the same.
10. The two loops over `step` and `i` can be combined into a single loop using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)
11. I would avoid the special case `if step == 0` by having a separate loop to handle that case:

    ```
    rmq_map = {(i, 0): m for i, m in enumerate(numbers)}
    ```

    and then looping over `step` starting from 1.
12. In Python it is usual to represent a range in *half-open* fashion (exclusive at the upper end). It would be convenient if `rmq_query` took its arguments in the same way.
13. The top-level code runs a single range query but does not check that the result is correct. It would be easy to check the result of `rmq_query(start, end)` against `min(numbers[start:end+1])`. It would then be easy to turn this into a unit test using the features in the [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) module.

#### 2. Revised code

```
from itertools import product

class RangeMinimum(object):
    "Data structure providing efficient range-minimum queries."

    def __init__(self, numbers):
        "Build a RangeMinimum object for the given sequence of numbers."
        # Mapping from (start, step) to min(numbers[start:start + 2**step])
        self._rmq = rmq = {(i, 0): m for i, m in enumerate(numbers)}
        n = len(numbers)
        for step, i in product(range(1, n.bit_length()), range(n)):
            j = i + 2 ** (step-1)
            if j < n:
                rmq[i, step] = min(rmq[i, step-1], rmq[j, step-1])
            else:
                rmq[i, step] = rmq[i, step-1]

    def query(self, start, stop):
        "Return min(numbers[start:stop])."
        j = (stop - start).bit_length() - 1
        x = self._rmq[start, j]
        y = self._rmq[stop - 2 ** j, j]
        return min(x, y)

import unittest
import random

class TestRangeMinimum(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_range_minimum(self):
        n = 1000
        numbers = [random.randrange(n) for _ in range(n)]
        rmq = RangeMinimum(numbers)
        for _ in range(n):
            start, stop = sorted(random.sample(range(n + 1), 2))
            self.assertEqual(rmq.query(start, stop), min(numbers[start:stop]))
```

#### 3. Generalization

There's nothing special about the *minimum* here — exactly the same algorithm can be used for range-*maximum* queries, or for querying other kinds of statistic on a range (such as the longest common prefix, or the union of sets).

So that suggests this kind of generalization:

```
from itertools import product

class RangeQuery(object):
    "Data structure providing efficient range queries."

    def __init__(self, items, fn):
        """Build a RangeQuery object for a sequence of items.

        fn -- function taking two items and returning their query
        result, for example "min" to query the range-minimum. It must be
        associative, commutative, and idempotent.

        """
        # Mapping from (start, step) to reduce(fn, items[start:start + 2**step])
        self._rq = rq = {(i, 0): item for i, item in enumerate(items)}
        self._fn = fn
        n = len(items)
        for step, i in product(range(1, n.bit_length()), range(n)):
            j = i + 2 ** (step-1)
            if j < n:
                rq[i, step] = fn(rq[i, step-1], rq[j, step-1])
            else:
                rq[i, step] = rq[i, step-1]

    def query(self, start, stop):
        "Return reduce(fn, items[start:stop])."
        j = (stop - start).bit_length() - 1
        x = self._rq[start, j]
        y = self._rq[stop - 2 ** j, j]
        return self._fn(x, y)

import random
import unittest

class TestRangeQuery(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_range_minmax(self):
        n = 1000
        items = [random.randrange(n) for _ in range(n)]
        rqmin = RangeQuery(items, min)
        rqmax = RangeQuery(items, max)
        for _ in range(n):
            start, stop = sorted(random.sample(range(n + 1), 2))
            self.assertEqual(rqmin.query(start, stop), min(items[start:stop]))
            self.assertEqual(rqmax.query(start, stop), max(items[start:stop]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the great comments, Gareth and vote up. 1. 'because log makes approximations that can lead to errors' -- agree. 2. 'the second element of the key is a step, not an end index', agree.

Comment: BTW, do you think there are any bugs (I mean functional) in our logic/code (either my original code or your revised)? For functional bug, I mean in any (could be corner) case, our code does not return the right minimal value for a range query.

Comment: Re-read your code and one more question, in your generalization version, why it is generalized? I see very similar to your "Revised code".

Comment: @LinMa: Did you compare the two versions to see where they differ?

Comment: Hi Gareth, I might be lost in your intention in your code, I think your code is far from resolving LCA problem, but I could be wrong, please feel free to correct me. I have write a version of using MRQ to resolve LCA problem => http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154319/using-range-minimal-query-for-lowest-common-ancestor-lca, if you have advice there, appreciated!

Comment: At the same time, if you could clarity how your code fits LCA, it will be great.

Answer (score 4):

Just some really quick thoughts.

This:

```
j = 0
while 2 ** j - 1 < len(numbers):
    j += 1
j -= 1
```

can be written as:

```
from math import log

j = int(log(len_numbers, 2))
```

You're repeating `step - 1` and `2 ** (step - 1)`, it's probably a good idea to use variables for those.
You're also accessing an array by both index and value, that's what `enumerate` is for:

```
    for index, value in enumerate(numbers):
        if step == 0:
            rmq_map[(index, step)] = value
            continue
        prev_step = step - 1
        step_power = 2 ** prev_step
        if index + step_power < len_numbers:
            rmq_map[(index, step)] = min(rmq_map[(index, rev_step)], rmq_map[(index + step_power, prev_step)])
        else:
            rmq_map[(index, step)] = rmq_map[(index, prev_step)]
```

Also, `2 ** (step - 1)` is being calculated repeatedly, so there may be a slight performance increase if you keep a dictionary to cache the results. Not entirely sure though, because the overhead of using a dictionary may be too much for such a simple operation. The same goes for `j`.

Comment: Thanks ChatterOne, love your comments and vote up. Besides the comments, do you think any code (functional/logical) bugs in my code or revised version?

Comment: BTW, how do you handle the issue @Gareth raised, for the math log issue?

Comment: @LinMa I know about the limitations of using `log`, it all depends on which space you're working. @Gareth did not chose 2^48 randomly, because up to 2^47 there's no problem. Integer arithmetic also has limits, they're just higher. Also nowadays depending on cpu/architecture, floating point math can be either slower or faster than integer operations. So as to which one to use I'd say "it depends".

Answer (score 2):

A tiny detail not mentionned by ChatterOne's excellent answer.

```
        if step == 0:
            rmq_map[(i,step)] = numbers[i]
            continue
        if i + 2 ** (step-1) < len(numbers):
            rmq_map[(i,step)] = min(rmq_map[(i, step-1)], rmq_map[(i + 2 ** (step-1), step-1)])
        else:
            rmq_map[(i,step)] = rmq_map[(i, step-1)]
```

could be written with an `elif` and no `continue`.

```
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if step == 0:
            rmq_map[(i,step)] = numbers[i]
        elif i + 2 ** (step-1) < len(numbers):
            rmq_map[(i,step)] = min(rmq_map[(i, step-1)], rmq_map[(i + 2 ** (step-1), step-1)])
        else:
            rmq_map[(i,step)] = rmq_map[(i, step-1)]
```

Comment: Thanks Josay, love your comments and vote up. Besides the comments, do you think any code (functional/logical) bugs in my code or revised version?