# Using range minimal query for lowest common ancestor (LCA)

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x, tree

Here is my code to use [range minimal query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query) to resolve the LCA problem. Any advice on code bugs, performance improvement in terms of algorithm time complexity, code style are appreciated.

More specifically, my questions are:

1. I am using in-order traverse to build depth array. Should I use other traverse, like pre-order (dfs), level-order, or post order?
2. I am using two additional data structures, `index_node_map` and `node_index_map`. I'm wondering if there are any ways to remove them, as they make my code seem lengthy.

Major ideas of my idea are:

1. Build depth array of each node by in-order traverse
2. Build MRQ index for depth array built in first step
3. For any two nodes, their LCA are the lowest depth node between them (in depth array)

```
from collections import defaultdict
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, value, left, right):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.index_node_map = defaultdict(int)
        self.node_index_map = defaultdict(int)
        self.depth = []
        self.rmp_map = defaultdict(tuple) # key: (index, step), value: (min value, index)
    def in_order(self, root, level):
        if root.left:
            self.in_order(root.left, level+1)
        self.depth.append(level)
        self.index_node_map[len(self.depth)-1]=root.value
        self.node_index_map[root.value] = len(self.depth)-1
        if root.right:
            self.in_order(root.right, level+1)
    def build_depth_index(self, root, level):
        self.in_order(root, level)
        print self.depth
        print self.index_node_map
        print self.node_index_map
        self.build_rmq_map(self.depth)

    def build_rmq_map(self, result):
        step = len(result).bit_length()
        for i in range(len(result)):
            self.rmp_map[(i,0)]=(result[i],i)
        for s in range(1, step+1):
            for i in range(len(result)):
                if i + 2 **(s-1) < len(result):
                    self.rmp_map[(i,s)] = min(self.rmp_map[(i,s-1)],self.rmp_map[(i+2**(s-1),s-1)])
                else:
                    self.rmp_map[(i,s)] = self.rmp_map[(i, s-1)]

    def rmp_query(self, index1, index2):
        step = (index2 - index1).bit_length()-1
        x = self.rmp_map[(index1, step)]
        y = self.rmp_map[(index2+1-2**(step), step)]
        # return index of depth array min value
        if x[0] < y[0]:
            return x[1]
        else:
            return y[1]

    def lca_query(self, node1, node2):
        index1 = self.node_index_map[node1]
        index2 = self.node_index_map[node2]
        min_index = self.rmp_query(index1, index2)
        return self.index_node_map[min_index]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = TreeNode(1, TreeNode(2, TreeNode(4, None, None), TreeNode(5, None, None)), TreeNode(3, TreeNode(6, None, None),TreeNode(7,None,None)))
    s = Solution()
    s.build_depth_index(root, 0)
    print s.lca_query(4,5)
    print s.lca_query(4, 7)
```

Comment: Please comment your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This review describes my thoughts as a fellow competitive programmer.

## About your questions

1. In-order traversal is a must here. Otherwise the RMQ-based algorithm won't work - it requires that for each vertexes A and B their LCA occurs between any occurrences of A and B.
2. You will need some kind of maps to map tree node to their position in the RMQ array. So, at least one of them should stay. However, you can get rid of `index_node_map` if you make RMQ store node's "value" (which is actually node's id, as far as I understood from your code).

## Major problems

1. Your code does not satisfy [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) at least in terms of whitespaces (it's easy to check and fix with tools like `pep8`, `flake8`, `autopep8`), that significantly reduces readability.
2. You have [God object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) in the solution, which, well, "solves the problem". Meaning, it mixes together *all of the following*:

   1. In-order traversal of a tree.
   2. Mapping between tree nodes and their indexes in the traversal.
   3. Calculating depths of vertexes.
   4. Reducing LCA to RMQ with
   5. Solution of RMQ problem with sparse table.

   Moreover, all these are highly tied together and you cannot, say, debug RMQ separately. It is a very common problem among competitive programmers (especially beginners). Though, some do not consider it to be a problem, but you're posting on codereview.
3. You initialize object outside of constructor, in the `build_depth_index` function. It may lead to a false conclusion that one may re-use the object with different inputs by calling `build_depth_index` with new tree. Despite ["work in the constructor"](https://dzone.com/articles/fixing-the-constructor-anti-pattern) being a kind of anti-pattern, I feel it's OK to move all initialization to the constructor in this case:

   1. You won't be able to reuse or not initialize the object.
   2. You will have less mutable state to care about (as opposed to the "initialize everything in `build_depth_index` and make the object reusable" approach), which is generally helpful for debugging.
4. There are a bunch of implicit invariants, e.g.:

   1. You assume that all values in the tree are different. It's not enforced with `assert`s, so it's possible to accidentally apply your algorithm to "wrong" tree and get "almost correct" results.
   2. In the `in_order` function you assume that each vertex occurs in the in-order traversal only once (because you "reenumerate" vertexes), but it's not the case for non-binary trees. Algorithm is more general than that. I'd suggest to avoid writing general algorithms for some "specific" cases because that is prone to copy-pasting and makes the algorithm harder to debug.
5. There is some debug output in the middle, which cannot be switched off.
6. No need in `defaultdict`s. I'd suggest to avoid `defaultdict`s when implementing data structures (esp. RMQ) because typically you should initialize the structure *first* and use it afterwards.
7. > `self.rmp_map = defaultdict(tuple) # key: (index, step), value: (min value, index)`

   you represent two-dimensional array with `dict`. Please don't do that, use arrays.
8. Use `namedtuple` instead of regular tuples to improve readability.

## My suggestions

### Get rid of God object

I'd suggest the following objects and functions:

```
class Rmq:
    def __init__(self, array, key):
        """Initializes RMQ structure for 'array', assuming that the value
        being minimized is returned by the 'key' function, if applied to
        array element"""

    def get_minimal_element(self, l, r):
        """Returns minimal element of array from position l to r (inclusive)"""

def get_in_order_traverse(tree):
    """Traverses tree in-order and returns a list of nodes."""

def get_depths(tree):
    """Calculates depths of all vertexes in the tree and returns mapping
    from vertex's value to its depth (root's depth is 0)."""

class Lca:
    def __init__(self, tree):
        """Initializes LCA solver for the given tree."""

    def get_lca(self, a, b):
        """Given two vertexes a and b returns their LCA as a TreeNode."""
```

Of course, that design can be de-coupled even further. Say, `Lca.__init__` can take an optional argument specifying `Rmq`'s factory so we can plug different implementations of `Rmq` for debugging.

### Other suggestions

1. Rename `TreeNode.value` to `TreeNode.id`, because LCA does care about node "values", it cares about their ids only.
2. Even better approach is to make `TreeNode`s hashable by overloading `__hash__` and `__eq__` so functions do not depend anymore on "what is node's id and how to find it".
3. Replace `TreeNode.left` and `TreeNode.right` with a list called `TreeNode.children`. For the sake of generality - algorithm does not care.
4. Use `logging` module for debug output so it can be switched on/off dynamically.
5. Use `namedtuple` instead of tuples.
6. In your sparse table implementation you can ignore all those segments which extend beyond array's length and get rid of `if`. You never need to access them, as all requests to RMQ lie inside the original array.

Comment: Thanks yeputons, for your comments -- " if you make RMQ store node's "value"", wondering how to make RMQ store values? I think RMQ needs to store node depth in order to work since RMQ order by depth? If I mis-understand your points, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: BTW, for your comments, "There is some debug output in the middle, which cannot be switched off.", what bug do you mean?

Comment: @LinMa right now your sparse table stores pair of two numbers: depth (which participates in finding minimal value) and index (which is the "result" returned by RMQ). My suggestion is to store vertex's "value" instead of that "index" and avoid extra conversion. About "debug output": you have some `print` statements which are not required by problem's statement.

Comment: Thanks yeputons, love your comments and mark your reply as answer. And grant the bounty points. I have make a new post here (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/155076/using-range-minimal-query-for-lowest-common-ancestor-lca-part-2), your advice is highly appreciated. I applied your comments to break down God object (but in a different way), and also applied your comments to save one of the map (I only use node to index map).

Comment: BTW, for your comments of "Rename TreeNode.value to TreeNode.id", I reserve my option since `id` is a Python internal identifier. If I am wrong, please correct me.

Comment: @LinMa you're welcome. Thank you. I have thought about `id` being builtin function and checked with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497883/in-python-is-it-bad-to-create-an-attribute-called-id).

Comment: Thanks yeputons, if you like, we can continue discussion in the new question here => http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/155076/using-range-minimal-query-for-lowest-common-ancestor-lca-part-2